# Get the currently selected Outlook Appointment

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to have a button in Outlook that changes the category of the selected Outlook Appointment (while in the calendar window) to the 'Green Category'.

```vb
Sub set_to_solved()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    
    Dim citem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    
    citem.Categories = "Green Category"
    
End Sub
```

I'm thinking I'm not referencing the selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you never initialize the `citem` valuable, secondly, you never save the appointment after setting the `Categories` property.

```
dim citem As object
for each citem in Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
  if citem.Class = 26 Then 'olAppointment 
    citem.Categories = "Green Category"
    citem.Save
  End If
next
```

Comment: thanks! sadly it triggers OBJECT REQUIRED for  if item.Class = 26 Then 'olAppointment

Comment: change `item` to `citem`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Explorer.Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection) property which returns a `Selection` object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window. The location of a selection in the explorer can be in the view list, the appointment list or task list in the To-Do Bar, or the daily tasks list in a calendar view. For more information, see the [Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selection.location) property.

```
Sub GetSelectedItems() 
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer 
 Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection 
 Dim oMail As Outlook.AppointmentItem
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
 
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer  
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection 
 
 Dim MsgTxt as String

 For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count  
  If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olAppointment Then 
   ' For appointment item, use the Organizer property. 
   Set oAppt = myOlSel.Item(x) 
   MsgTxt = oAppt.Organizer 
  End If
 Next
 
 ' Debug.Print MsgTxt 
 MsgBox MsgTxt
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eugene thanks for your answer but sadly it gives the error ' Next without For ' when I try to test